# postgres dump compression options to AWS RDS

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, rds

I'm currently pushing local data up to a AWS RDS db - but because of the data size, this is taking a long time. Was hoping someone might be able to suggest a way to get the dump file compressed before sending up (and then getting it read at the other end)

Currently the dump file is being written thus:

```
pg_dump -t properties_staging --data-only project_development > data/properties_staging.dump
```

And pushed up to AWS this way:

```
psql -a -h blahblahblah.blahblahblah.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com -U master -d ebdb -p 5432 < data/properties_staging.dump
```

What are the best options available for slimming this dump file down while still punting it up to RDS?

All suggestions very gratefully received.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_dump` supports several options that may be faster and/or result in smaller files. From the documentation, some options to try. Note this is very dependent on your data, and some choices will require you to use `pg_restore` instead of `psql`.

### pg_dump options

- `--format=custom` use a binary format, compressed by default.
- `--format=directory` create multiple files in dump. compressed by default. Allows parallel dumps.
- `--jobs=N` use N threads for dump and compression. May speed up operation.
- `--compress=N` number from 0 to 9. Zero is no compression, one is low-cpu compression, 9 is high-cpu compression. [Here's a quick summary of what this means](https://serverfault.com/a/253075/107854).

Again, what will be the fastest? I don't know. Test and benchmark for your specific situation. It'll likely be faster if you copy the output of pg_dump to an EC2 instance (with a fairly fast CPU, not a micro or t2) in the same AZ and run `pg_restore` or `psql` from there.

Note `pg_restore` has a `--jobs=N` flag too. This setting doesn't need to match the one in `pg_dump`.

Comment: very helpful - I had seen the documentation, but your extra input made it make sense. thanks tedder.
also, i found that you can push up to RDS from local using pg_restore as per http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66372/moving-a-postgres-database-from-standalone-local-db-to-amazon-rds - i guess there is no disadvantage to this is there?